# Mean squared error of a noisy random variable

Tags: probability

Assume we have a distribution D, and a random variable X from this distribution. We want to estimate E(D) through X. Obv E(X) is an estimator for E(D). The question is that does the MSE (=mean squared error) of estimator decreases if we shrink the estimation a little bit? Let's call m1 = E(X) and m2 = E(X) - eps then is this true:

MSE(E(D) - m2) <= MSE(E(D) - m1)

I dont understand why this should be true. Does it bring any difference if D = G+N where G is a Gaussian distirbution and N is some noise?

Comment: I think you are asking about a linear transformation, i.e. you are taking all of the values observed and subtracting a fixed amount from each observation.  If you do that, it wouldn't have any effect on MSE.  But maybe you are asking something quite different.  Care to define eps?

Comment: What is the difference between what you call $E(D)$ and the _expected_ value $E[X]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It actually increases.

Let "e" be the estimate, and "t" be the true value.

MSE(e) = Var(e) + Bias^2(e, t)

Now, since you are shrinking the estimate,

MSE(e - eps) = var(e - eps) + Bias^2(e - eps, t)

For simplicity, and without loss of generality, if we assume "e" is an unbiased estimate of "t", then

Bias^2(e - eps, t) = E[eps^2] = eps^2.

Variance doesn't change when a constant is subtracted, so essentially, you are increasing the MSE by eps^2.